# You have already flag this post - is missing

Tags: bug, flags

When you flag a post you see a dialog like below image,

> [image]

Now when you click on flag link for the same post again, you got this dialog with message mentioning "You have already flag this post" but today I see that the title is missing, However when I click on flag button it showed me same message "You have already flag this post for moderator attention".

As far as I remember when I flag an answer as NAA and again click on the flag link then it shows me disabled option button for "NAA" option but allow me to flag other options with dialog title "You have already flag this post".

So my question is, Have you done some change to flagging system or is this missing title is bug ?

When I flag a question for closure ( which I did in past when I had less that 2K reputation, but still question is open ) the flag dialog shows me "You have already flag this question for closure".

Comment: Close votes aren't really considered flags.  I've always seen the UI change when I've already voted to close, but I've never seen the UI change when I've already flagged an answer.

Comment: @KirkWoll users below 3K , 2K uses flag to close a question.